I have a problem with passing variable from my main blade to component
enter image description hereenter image description here
Body:
I’m developing a web application using Laravel 11, and I’ve encountered an issue with Blade components. When I attempt to pass data to a component, they show me error that undefined $publication . This problem does not occur when running the same code in Laravel 10.
I’ve already checked the controller, and $publications is correctly passed to the view with the expected data. There are no errors displayed, just empty content where I expect the publication details.
What I’ve tried:
•   Verifying the $publications variable is not null in the controller.
•   Ensuring the variable names match between the component and the view.
•   Clearing Laravel’s view cache with php artisan view:clear.

None of these steps have resolved the issue. I’m looking for insights on what might be causing this behavior in Laravel 11 and how I can fix it.
